# Which Pipelines are used for the build status of commits and branches in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

If you set up multiple pipelines for the same repository, it seems *any* (the most recently run) of the builds will count as the "status" for a specific commit or branch, when viewed in the DevOps web interface.

Is it possible to control which Pipeline is blessed as the "important" one? Example: here is a commit with a status badge saying "succeeded". But the build that succeeded wasn't my main  CI build, it was just one of a dozen auxillary builds that are also run for the code. Is there any way to tell DevOps which build is my "main" CI build? Or, conversely, to tell DevOps that some other build should *not* count towards the status of a commit or branch?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Browsing the documentation it looks like that badge is [scoped to the branch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/badge/get-build-badge-data?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) and you can't define an "important" pipeline.  Going forward it looks like you'd either have to create a custom badge that tracks the "important" build or you might consider a branching strategy that would allow the auxiliary builds to have their own main branches.